# "patient recommended to drink water" - how to encode in SNOMED/FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir, snomed-ct

How would the procedure: "patient recommended to drink more water" be encoded as a SNOMED expression (or a FHIR procedure?)

Are there public guidelines for encoding records? SNOMED's docs seem to be a little sparse on examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have expected a child concept of [229807004 |Recommendation to change food and drink intake (procedure)|](http://ontoserver.csiro.au/shrimp/?concept=229807004&system=http://snomed.info/sct) for this.

Best solution is to request the concept from your SNOMED National Release Centre.

Failing that, or in the meantime, you could use this concept as-is, with text (eg in a CodeableConcept) indicating the additional detail ("drink more water").